# Isotope not working

Tags: jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry

Am using isotope to layout files in a grid. I've been using masonry on the same script, works well but I need the filtering options that isotope. Am getting a  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'masonry' of undefined` when trying to run the script. In firefox, I get the following error:

`TypeError: isotope.options is undefined`
Below is what am running

`var container = document.querySelector('#allstories');
 iso = new Isotope( container, {
   itemSelector: '.grid_story'
 } );`

Does anyone have an idea of whats wrong?

Comment: if you solve your problem by any answer, at least, please appreciate him by just click the up arrow.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty limited code to answer your question but I can see one problem, your missing a "var":

```
var container = document.querySelector('#allstories');
var iso = new Isotope( container, {
itemSelector: '.grid_story'
});
```